# A finite sum of trigonometric functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, summation

By taking real and imaginary parts in a suitable exponential equation, prove that

$$\begin{align*}
\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi jk}{n}\right)&=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if } k \text{ divides } n\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi jk}{n}\right)&=0
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Do you know how to sum a finite geometric series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: 
$$\exp(ix)=\cos(x)+i\cdot \sin(x)$$ 
and 
$$\exp(2\cdot i\cdot\pi \cdot k)=1+0 \cdot i$$
for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.
and for $q\neq 1$, we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^n q^k = \frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}$$
For $q=1$ we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^n q^k = n+1$$

Comment: Ah, ah! Note you miss an $i$ in your second formula.

Comment: @julien Do you want to answer? Sorry again.

Comment: I was not serious about the rule...My personal rule is: if there is already a prior answer to mine  and mine is not significantly different, I most often delete mine, or simply refrain from posting it. If you add $q\neq 1$ and correct the typo $k+1=n+1$, I'll upvote yours.

Comment: @julien oh fixed it

Comment: @julien Sorry but i don't quite understand... what does q here stand for?

Comment: @catsensei as long as you get an injective e function the equality $\exp(n\cdot k)=\exp(n)^k$ holds

Comment: @CatSensei First, take the summation over $j$, not $k$. Then apply it to $q=e^{2i\pi k/n}$. Then separate real and imaginary parts.